# How do I get reverse reference in Django template?

Tags: python, django

Apologies if the title doesn't make much sense. I don't quite understand what I lack in knowledge. 
I have a Post and Comment models in my Django project. What I'm trying to do is list out all the `Blog` posts, and show **NUMBER OF COMMENTS OF EACH POST**. Please see my codes below.

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=10000, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

class Comment(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    post = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
```

views.py

```
def main_page(request):
    all_blogs = Blog.objects.all()
    
    context = {
        'blog' : blog,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

template

```
{% for b in blog %}
<div>
    <p>{{b.title}}</p>
    <div>
        {{WHERE THE NUMBER OF THIS POST'S COMMENTS IS DISPLAYED}}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

All I need is the number of the comments, but have no idea how to do it. Is there a way to make this possible in the template? Or do I have to add some codes in `views.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can annotate the `Blog` objects with the number of related `Comment`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def main_page(request):
    all_blogs = Blog.objects.annotate(
        num_comments=Count('comment')
    )
    context = {
        'blogs' : blogs
    }
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', context)
```

The `Blog` objects that arise from that queryset will have an extra attribute `.num_comments` with the number of related comments:

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
<div>
    <p>{{ blog.title }}</p>
    <div>
        {{ blog.num_comments }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```